# Store Array thats Located Inside Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the following JSON:

```
"list": {
            "list_id": "2kA",
            "title": "Social Media",
            "description": "Trending",
            "image": [
                "http://cdn.socialmediaexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/br-campaign-report.png?9d7bd4",
                "http://cdn.socialmediaexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/br-campaign-report.png?9d7bd"
            ],
            "views": 65
        }
```

How can I store a serialized version of the image array in the database? Doing any of the following returns an error:

```
$images = $item->list->image;
$images = $item->list->image->[0];
$images = $item->list->['image'];
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: No need to serialize again? JSON itself is in serialized format. Store the JSOn to DB and while retrieving you can go fo json_decode()

Comment: I'm pulling it from an API and caching the results in the DB. I will decrypt the JSON on the view end, but this is a simple cron to cache results.

Answer (score 1):

you can access to your images like this:

```
foreach($item->list->image as $your_image) {
    //do what you want
}
```

or use a associated array like this

```
$x = json_decode('{"list": {
            "list_id": "2kA",
            "title": "Social Media",
            "description": "Trending",
            "image": [
                "a",
                "b"
            ],
            "views": 65
        }}', true);

foreach($x['list']['image'] as $your_image) {
    //do what you want
}
```

to save it to your db use json_encode (and escape), as example of a mysqli connection

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO your_table (...)
          VALUES (\''.mysqli_real_escape_string($dblink, json_encode($your_array)).'\')';
```

on select you can use json_decode!

Comment: I want to store the entire "images" array in a DB field. I'm already using JSON decode on the entire object, and extracting the list_id, title, description & views fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
In your DB, data is in JSON, literally it means its a formatted string like:    
"something here...."

You cannot access it by "->" as it is not an object.  

So,
Convert your string(JSON) to Object to access like these:
$x['list']['image'] 
It can be achieved by json decoding your string which will convert your string to object

There was a bad error in code too. This one : $item->list->image->[0]; 
you cannot access an element of an array like this image->[0] --> it should be 
$item->list->image[0]
```

Comment: $images = $item->list->image[0]; works well. Only issue is that it only pulls the FIRST array item. How can I store ALL?

Comment: dude i mean this only but  concentrated on image array only. your code was $item->list->image->[0];